# assembler addressing in AT&T

Tags: assembly

Can anyone explain what this line means:

```
mov %esi,0x4(%edi)
```

the second parameter is the destiny. does it mean, my target is the address %edi incremented with 4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This moves the contents of the register esi to address stored in edi + 4 (bytes). Pseudo-C:

```
uint32_t* p = %edi;
p[1] = %esi; // Note subscript '1'. This is the same as p + 4
```